# Cheapest mac for latest xcode?

Tags: ios, mac, xcode, swift

I am doing a uni course which is called iPhone Software Engineering and it says that I need a mac that is able to run latest version of 'Xcode' for app developement and current SWIFT and the Apple iOS SDK will be used. So far I have done many programming languages using windows and this is the only course that requires a mac so I need suggestions to buy a cheap mac that will only be good for programming purposes. I don't need any good graphics and all that. Since I am low on budget I would be happy if my mac could fulfill my course requirements.

Comment: Check out developer transition kit, something like a mac mini

Answer (score 2):

The least expensive mac is the Mac mini. It comes without a monitor, keyboard, or mouse so you can use the items from your PC. A new Mac Mini sells for $800. If that is still too pricey you could maybe find a used older mac on Ebay or similar sites. Beware because Macs have a high resale value. So always check the price.

If your needing the latest XCode, be sure that the computer can run Mojave or Catalina operating systems. A computer from 2013 or later should be fine. If you are just learning to code then you can maybe get a cheap laptop or the Mac Mini.

You should check the Apple site to confirm what models can run the latest version of Xcode. My 2013 number was just from memory. The actual compatibility list is given below.

```
MacBook (Early 2015 or newer)
MacBook Air (Mid 2012 or newer)
MacBook Pro (Mid 2012 or newer)
Mac mini (Late 2012 or newer)
iMac (Late 2012 or newer)
iMac Pro (2017)
Mac Pro (Late 2013, plus mid-2010 and mid-2012 models with recommended Metal-capable GPU)
```

Comment: It might be worth getting a generation later as some of those will not run the new OS/Xcode which is in beta now. This is irrelevant for a current course but if you want to keep up with newer versions.